# My if-else statement only works once

Tags: java

First question here, so please do not be rude...

Anyway, I recently discovered a problem with if/else if. Showing the code written down below. The problem is that my else if parentesis only works once. When i have written a word matching the one from the register the else if won't work anymore. Is it any errors in the code or is it netbeans that is bugging me out? Would appreciate any help I can get. 
Hope you can understand the syntax even though it is written on swedish...

```
private void årsök_txfActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    try {
       int söktår = Integer.valueOf(årsök_txf.getText());
       info_txa.setText("");
        for (Register register1 : register) {
            int finns = register1.getAr();
            if (finns==söktår) {
                info_txa.append(register1 + "");
                hittad = true;
            } else if (hittad==false) {
                info_txa.setText("Tyvärr så utgavs det inga filmer "+söktår);
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vänligen mata in ett tal som sökt utgivningsår!");
    }  
}
```

Comment: Was it planned to not have a case where it doesn't enter the first if, but where `hittad==true`? because as it is now, as soon as you enter the first `if` statement, you will never enter the `if (hittad==false)` code block.

Comment: in the `if` you set `hittad` to `true`  and then you `else if`  checks if it is `false` so after you hit the first `if` once, the `else if` cannot be hit because `hittad` is false.  And since `hittad` seems to be defined in the class, unless you have some other code that sets it back to `false` , it will always be `true` and the `else if` cannot be hit ever.

Comment: If i understood you correctly, no. I do not want to have a case when hittad==true. Just want my program to search after a specific year. I the program contains the specific year I want it to tell the user that, if not it should put out "Your searched year was not found" but in swedish. The problem however is that it only works the until the first match, after that the program just puts out an blank answer...

Comment: That is because `hittad` is never reseted to false.

Comment: @litelite That seems to be the problem actually, any suggestions of how to solve it? Just put hittad ==false; at the very start of the actionperformed class?

Comment: Declare `hittad` in the method

Comment: And shouln't the "not found" message be outside the loop?

Comment: @litelite Does it matter? (I'm a newbie)

Comment: @ArvidLagerström in you case it will work. But it can be a bit confusing to read and understand.

Comment: @litelite okay, thank you so much for the fast response and help. Will think about that "syntax error" in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not very clear. But this is definitely a coding error and nothing to do with Netbeans. This is what I understood, please confirm if this is what you mean:
Once Register contains a word that matches `söktår`, after that `else-if` block is not executed.

The reason for the `else if` to not get executed is that it only gets executed if `hittad` is false, and once you find the match, you set `hittad` to be true so it will never enter the `else-if` block after that.

Comment: You did accept my question correctly, and you are right with the solution too. Thank you and litelite so much for the fast responses and help!

Comment: Was just waiting for the "timer" to run out, could't do it before.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your if block ,You have  assign  'hittad = true' ,but have not  reset it again ,since your else if have condition as  'hittad==false' which will never true again ,so else if block will never execute after execution of if block  code.
Hope It will help for you.

Comment: Exactly, thank you so much. The damn tunnel-vision hits me everytime i occur a problem in my code...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand from your comments what you are trying to accomplish, then perhaps the loop could be greatly simplified as so (only showing general example structure):

```
Boolean found = false;

for(obj : objects)
    if (obj.equals(searchCriteria)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }

if (!found)
    system.out.println("object not found.");
```

Comment: It does indeed seems and looks better, gladly accepting any help I can get.